# Php mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, heroku, smtp, phpmailer

I had not any problems before, but i have checked today and i get the following error: **Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed**.  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting. I run my website on **Heroku app**. I use the latest version of **php Mailer** with **google smtp** servers. Are there any alternative smtp servers i can use? Here is my Script:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


    if(empty($_POST['Email'])){
        $_POST['Email']= "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['Name'])){
        $_POST['Name']= "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['Subject'])){
        $_POST['Subject']= "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['message'])){
        $_POST['message']= "";
    }


if (isset($_POST["message"]) && !empty($_POST["message"])) {

   $mymail=smtpmailer("webdominar1@gmail.com",$_POST['Email'], 
$_POST['Name'], $_POST['Subject'], $_POST['message']);  


}else{  
    header('Location: http://webdominar.xyz'); exit();

}



function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';  
    $mail->Password = '1234';          
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = "Webdominar Contact form ~Name: $from_name ~ subject: $subject
 on http://webdominar.xyz ";
    $mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Body = "blabla" ; //end body


    $mail->AddAddress($to);
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else {
    echo "Well done $from_name, your message has been sent!\nWe will reply to the following email: $from"
            . "<br>Your Message: $body";
}




} //end function smtpmailer



?>
```

Comment: Silly question but have you tried setting the SMTP up in a mail client to ensure this works. You could be trying to diagnose code only to find its an email issue.

Comment: have you checked the login parameters to google's smtp server?

Comment: this form was working a week ago. I faced the problem today maybe i can try to use microsoft smtp servers but i can't find the settings. This problem is maybe a host issue.

Comment: okay, problem solved, it seemed to be a host issue and now it is fixed